# Trouble with calculating distance between two points

Tags: geometry

I'm trying to find the distance between two points for a question in my textbook. The points are P(-2, 3) and Q(1, -3). Here's the working I have so far:

d = $\sqrt{(x_1 - x_0)^2 + (y_1 - y_0)^2}$

d = $\sqrt{(1 - (-2))^2 + (-3 - 3)^2}$

d = $\sqrt{3^2 + -6^2}$

d = $\sqrt -27$

This results in "Math ERROR" on my calculator.
Where am I going wrong?

Comment: How can the square of $-6$ be negative?

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown when I do -6^2 on my calculator it gives me -36

Comment: Why are you using your calculator for such a simple problem?

Comment: Because I don't trust myself to do it manually

Comment: But you _do_ trust yourself to do it on a calculator? Hmm. Anyway, to get the square of $-6$, you press $6$ then $\pm$ then $x^2$. Not $6$ then $x^2$ then $\pm$. That would be $-(6^2)$, when what you want is $(-6)^2$.

Comment: @TonyK that is what I did

Comment: I can hardly believe that. Try it on Windows Calculator if you have it handy: $6$, then $\pm$, then $x^2$.

Comment: Ok, it works on windows calculator, but not on my calculator. I think my calculator is evaluating it as $-(6^2)$

Comment: You press $6$, then $\pm$, then $x^2$, and it shows you $-36$? You should throw it in the bin.

Answer (score 0):

Your mistake is
$(-3-3)^2=(-6)^2=36,$ not $-36$.

You must use brackets when squaring a negative number on your calculator.

Comment: You don't need brackets. On Windows Calculator: $3\, x^2\, +\, 6\, \pm\, x^2\, =$.

Answer (score 0):

It is $$d=\sqrt{(1-(-2))^2+(-3-3)^2}=\sqrt{(1+2)^2+(-6)^2}=\sqrt{9+36}=...$$

Answer (score 0):

You are getting the error as you have a negative under the square root. When calculating the distance formula, you denoted $(-6)^2=-36$ rather than $36$ causing you to get the error. Try $\sqrt{9+36}$.

Comment: or $\sqrt{9+36}$.